# Node-Orm hasOne relationship is not formed correctly

Tags: node.js, node-orm2

```
var User = db.define('user', {
    user_id : Number,

    work_phone : String,
    mobile_phone : String
}, {
    id: 'user_id'
    , autoFetch: true
    , cache: true
}) ;


var UserCloud = db.define('user_cloud', {
    id : Number,
    file_path : String,
    user_id : Number,
    file_size : String, //not used
    date_added : Date,
    date_modified : Date,
    is_disclaimer : Number,
    folder_id : String

}, {
    autoFetch: true
}) ;


UserCloud.hasOne('user', User, {
        field: 'user_id'
        , autoFetch: true
 })
```

This relationship doesn't form!  It sets up the functions getUser and hasUser on the UserCloud instances, but it doesn't set the user property.

However setting a simlar hasOne relationship up on user works for other "Classes".  Further the UserCloud has other relationships that are unformed as well.

I don't know what other examples to give, nor do I know where to look.  I didn't see anything in One.js that provided direction, I am really in the dark here and looking for any pointers / insight.

Comment: You should not be using node-orm2.It is not really clean since mongodb is a NoSQL databse, and mongoose is almost orm-like. I remember when I began I wanted to use it but I got so many problems that I gave up and used only mongoose. ORMs are a solution for the stupid and useless SQL because it is horrible, but you cannot apply it to a NoSQL databse. PHP and Node.js aren't the same thing...

Comment: I am using node-orm to a MySql database

Comment: Sorry then. BTW you could still mongodb + mongoose to achieve the same goal.

Comment: I can't it is a legacy database, not a new build

Answer (score 0):

OK this wasn't posted win the original question:

```
    var UserCloud = db.models.user_cloud
    var UserCloudFolder = db.models.user_cloud.user_cloud_folders
```

THe big issue is that there was an accidental chaining of models on the second model:

```
    var UserCloudFolder = db.models.user_cloud.user_cloud_folders\
```

SHould be

```
    var UserCloudFolder = db.models.user_cloud_folders
```

Which fixed it.  I discovered that orm was trying to link the UserCloud back to another UserCloud which lead me to look beyond the definition of the association.  SO there you have it - no errors, just not working.